# Subtract documents score based on their age in Apache SOLR

Tags: apache, solr

I'm trying to implement a kind of negative boost in Apache SOLR in such a way that, documents created within last 2 years should not have any effect on their score.

But documents created before NOW-2YEARS should be penalized based on there difference in number of days.For example if difference is 60 days then a plenty should be given to the score based on these days.

Any solution to this problem using Apache SOLR.

Edit:

So far I have used boost function of dismax using following function.

if(gt(ms(created_at,NOW-2YEARS),0),0,sub(query($q),mul(div(sub(ms(NOW),ms(NOW-2YEARS)),8.64e+7),0.2)))

The problem with this method is that, lets say if score of document which was created two years ago is 20 and the difference in days is 60 then doing subtraction give 20-60=-40 which is not correct.

Also I'm always getting  "query($q)":1.0, which doesn't make sense.

Thanks

Comment: so, what did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried to use boost function as folow:
if(gt(ms(created_at,NOW-2YEARS),0),0,sub(query($q),mul(div(sub(ms(NOW),ms(NOW-2YEARS)),8.64e+7),0.2)))

Comment: could you please add it to question and show what's the output was and why it's not suitable for you?

Comment: I have added the issue with this solution on question.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the logic of your function, but according to what you describe with words, I think this should be sufficient : 
    `{!boost b=recip(max(0,ms(NOW-2YEAR,created_at)),3.16e-11,1,1)}`  
This way, all documents younger than 2 years will be considered brand new and won't be applied any boost (penalty), older ones will be applied "normal" penalty as it would be the case with this one `recip(ms(NOW,created_at),3.16e-11,1,1)`. Give it a try !